# How to invoke a webservice with dataFormat as PAYLOAD

Tags: apache, web-services, apache-camel, cxf

I'm using camel 2.16.0

Created a camel route to invoke a web service, dataFormat as **MESSAGE** and i get the response normally.
and this route is invoked using ProducerTemlate

```
//payloadXml is a string which contains SOAP Request Message.
Object response = producerTemplate.requestBody("direct:invokeWS", payloadXml);

<route id="my_Sample_Camel_Route_with_CXF">
<from uri="direct:invokeWS" />
    <to uri="cxf://http://localhost:8111/camel_MQ/TestService?wsdlURL=http://localhost:8111/camel_MQ/TestService?wsdl&amp;serviceName={http://www.test.org/interface/test/ws}camel_MQ-ws&amp;portName={http://www.test.org/interface/test}TestEndpoint&amp;dataFormat=MESSAGE" />
<log message="------------->> ${body}" />
</route>
```

But once i change the **dataFormat** to "**PAYLOAD**"

I get exception.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The PayLoad elements cannot fit with the message parts of the BindingOperation. Please check the BindingOperation and PayLoadMessage.
    at org.apache.camel.component.cxf.CxfEndpoint$CamelCxfClientImpl.setParameters(CxfEndpoint.java:1171)
```

Tried creating CxfPayload and then sent that to producerTeamplate while invoking the WS, but still the same Exception,

Answer (score 1):

Finally I'm able to invoke WS using dataFormat as payload.
created CxfPayload object and added SOAP Headers and Body to it.

But still i was getting the same exception "The PayLoad elements cannot fit with the message parts of the BindingOperation"

Then I added defaultOperationName & defaultOperationNamespace headers while invoking the webservice as shown below.

```
<to uri="cxf:bean:camel_MQ_MQ-ws?dataFormat=PAYLOAD&amp;defaultOperationName=TestService&amp;defaultOperationNamespace=http://www.camel_MQ.org/interface&amp;loggingFeatureEnabled=true" />
```

hope this helps ;-)